# Erro ao realizar conexão entre API e Flutter (Dio)

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando aprender a utilizar o `Dio` para integrar uma API que estou desenvolvendo também e para isso tentei realizar um teste simples.

Eu simplesmente tentei fazer um print no terminal mesmo utilizando esse trecho de código:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  void teste() async {
    Response res;
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    res = await dio.get("192.168.15.10:3000/welcome");
    print(res.data.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Verifique o teste no terminal!!!:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: teste,
        child: Icon(Icons.adjust),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

A rota (Express) que estou utilizando no dio.get():

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: 'Parabéns você está conectado a API' })
})
```

Porém quando executo teste no app pressionando o botão, obtenho o seguinte erro (Como é muito grande, decidi upar uma captura de tela dele, visando não poluir muito a postagem):

https://ibb.co/8mY1xq5

O que fiz de errado? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Eu nunca usei esse Dio, já fiz acesso a API no Flutter usando uma dependência chamada http, eu sempre uso res.body. Tenta trocar o res.data por res.body.

Comment: Outra coisa, acho que você deve usar um widget chamado FutureBuilder para trabalhar com funções assíncrona. Vou colocar aqui uns códigos que eu fiz que talvez te ajude

Answer (score 1):

VIEW

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Users'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
            future: _placeHolderService.getUsers(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    Albums(snapshot.data[index].id)));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text('${snapshot.data[index].name}'),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text('${snapshot.data[index].email}')),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
              }
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }),
      ),
    );
```

SERVICE

```
class PlaceHolderService {
  final baseURL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  Future<List<Post>>getPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get('$baseURL/posts');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var objs = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      var posts = objs.map((obj) => Post.fromJson(obj)).toList();
      return posts;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erro ao buscar posts');
    }
  }

  Future<User> getPerfil() async {
    var response = await http.get('$baseURL/users/1');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return user;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erro ao buscar perfil do usuário');
    }
  }

  Future<List<Comment>>getComments(int postId) async {
    var response = await http.get('$baseURL/posts/$postId/comments');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var objs = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      var comments = objs.map((obj) => Comment.fromJson(obj)).toList();
      return comments;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erro ao buscar comentários');
    }
  }
}
```

MODEL

```
class Address {
  String street;
  String suite;
  String city;
  String zipcode;

  Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : street = json['street'],
        suite = json['suite'],
        city = json['city'],
        zipcode = json['zipcode'];
}
```